# python regex string concatenation vs literal

Tags: python, regex, string, concatenation

I'm trying to run a substitution regex but am see odd behavior.

In a loop I have:

```
var = "HELLO"
result = re.subn("\\b"+var+'\\b \\+ \\"', "sample_replacement_text", text)
```

This fails to work, but if I take the value of var and put it straight in  `result = re.subn('\\bHELLO\\b \\+ \\"', "sample_replacement_text", text)`

Any idea why? I've been sadly scratching my head for hours.

Comment: This is just a thought, but try doing '\\b' instead of "\\b" might be a way that you're escaping the characters

Comment: That or be consistent between them, I think the python interpreter might see the " ... " in the part before var and expect that after var but you are using ' ... ' instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with that regex, but here is what it does:

It looks for a pattern that begins with a word boundary, followed by your `var` word, followed by another boundary, followed by a `+`, and finally a `"`.  Here is an example of it in action:

```
import re
var = "HELLO"
result = re.subn("\\b"+var+'\\b \\+ \\"', "foo", 'word HELLO + " word more words')
print(result)
```

It  correctly removes `HELLO + "` and replaces it with foo.  If you intended to use the plus for further  concatenation instead of a literal, you should not escape it.

EDIT:

For a more real life example of what I'm trying to do, I have a config file that uses a placeholder variable that I want to substitue with a string literal:

```
visibility = [
    # blah blah comment
    VAR + ":sample_package",
    VAR + "/some_other_path",        
],
```

Running the replacement

```
var = 'VAR'
re.subn("\\b"+var+'\\b \\+ \\"', "my_replacement", text)
```

should yield

```
visibility = [
        # blah blah comment
        "my_replacement:sample_package",
        "my_replacement/some_other_path",        
],
```

but it remains unchanged

Comment: what you described is exactly what I want it to do, but it is not working.

Comment: Is it possible that multiple calls of re.subn on the result of a previous re.subn could be the issue?

Comment: Well - if you are calling it on a prior returned value, everything would already be substituted, so I don't think it would have any effect.

Comment: no im calling multiple replacements. I need to replace 5 variables with string literals in a config file:

Comment: In that example, VAR is not a string, it's a variable.

Comment: It's a string in the context that it lives in a file and I read that in as 'text'

Comment: I found my error, I missed a step in my for loop and accidently was re.subn'ing the original file with each pass of the loop rather than passing the result of each iteration forward.